# High Switching Coil Current Circuit

Tags: power-electronics, coil, electromagnetic, high-current

I've been working on building a circuit designed to handle a 40 A current with a switching time of less than 1 ms (currently using 500 us). I've attached the circuit for your review.

Initially, I utilized a MOSFET ([NTHL020N120SC1](https://www.onsemi.com/pdf/datasheet/nthl020n120sc1-d.pdf)), and although it worked initially, the MOSFET burnt out after a while. Subsequently, I switched to an IGBT ([IXGN200N60B3](https://www.littelfuse.com/media?resourcetype=datasheets&itemid=3bcbc160-cde1-41b8-aa97-23da892dcee0&filename=littelfuse-discrete-igbts-pt-ixgn200n60b3-datasheet)), only to encounter the same issue – the IGBT blew after a few seconds. I'm having trouble pinpointing the reason for these failures.

Could someone please assist me in identifying and resolving this issue?

[image]

Catch diode datasheet: [SCS220AM - SiC Schottky Barrier Diodes | Rohm](https://fscdn.rohm.com/en/products/databook/datasheet/discrete/sic/sbd/scs220am-e.pdf)

Comment: Have you looked at the drain-source voltage to see if it's ringing above VDS max?  What's your VPP voltage? Can you show the gate and drain waveforms?  What's your on and off time (duty cycle) and repetition rate? What's your layout like? Pics of the actual board?

Comment: Perhaps the Id or Uds was too much. To get something useful you should show how did you exactly calculate that point (Uds, Id) stays in the safe operating area. The inductance of L1 can be much lower than estimated if the core saturates and as a consequence Id grows much faster than estimated. We know nothing of the essential numbers because you keep them hidden. The given answer points one possible problem, but there can be more.

Comment: Is R2 10 or 18 ohms? (Some schematics have poor resolution fonts, and this image is pretty zoomed out, so it seems worth asking.)

Comment: Be very careful about any lead inductance supplying power the VPP power. That inductance could cause very high peak voltages across the MOSFET/IGBT on turn-off. It would be advisable to have a capacitor between VPP and GNDREF very close to the switch device.

Comment: Please post Id and Vds oscillograms.

Answer (score 5):

That 10 ohm resistor in your flyback suppression circuit (across the inductor) may be the problem.  If you're pulling 40A when you switch off, the 40A flyback current will provide 400V across that resistor.  This means that there will be VPP+400V on the drain of the FET.  A better option would be to choose a diode that can handle 40A peak pulsed current and eliminate (short) the resistor.

Comment: If faster decay of the coil current is needed, a small resistor or a zener diode is a good idea. In any case the diode will need to handle 40A peaks.

Comment: @TimWilliams Thanks for the catch, fixed.

Answer (score 2):

You don't say whether of not the Q1 is mounted to a heatsink.  The part could be overheating due to simple I^R losses.

Also, R1 works with the input capacitance of Q1 to form a sawtooth wave at the gate terminal.  This could slow the transistor's-turn on and turn-off times, incr4easing internal power dissipation.

R1 also limits the peak current in and out of the driver, another cause of slowing the Q1 times.

R1 is not mandatory; it is there to reduce gate ringing caused by wiring inductance *if there is any*.  Try lower values for R1 until ringing appears.